# I terrify those beneath

Tags: riddle, word, lateral-thinking

*My beginning: steamy, but 2/5ths crazy*
*My middle, wailing, from spectres hazy*
*My end, demonic, lives in Hell*
*My start, to there, does transport sell*
*My middle, within, the original man*
*My end, ends, an ender of lifespan*

Who am I?

**Hint #1:**

> *All shall fear my reflection*
>  *Its start starts matters of perplexion*
>  *Its middle lives beyond the pale*
>  *Its end is my start's last tale*

**Hint #2:**

> *The skulls, stopping, cackle and grin:*
>  *My start is not where I begin*
>  *My reflection is garbled and quite absurd*
>  *Maybe you've guessed - it's not truly a word*

**Hint #3:**

> *My beginning runs so desperately*
>  *From me why does it always flee?*
>  *My ends, each two, letters in sum*
>  *Are a mystery and madness to succumb*

**Hint #4:**

> *My letters are of number seven*
>  *Ask for more hints and I'll send you to heaven*

Comment: Would the 'knowledge' tag be useful here?  I'm finding a lot of connections in the realm of rot13(byq fgrnz ybpbzbgvirf naq Terrx zlgubybtl) but it's requiring a lot of research, so I'm afraid I may be chasing gooses.

Comment: @TwoBitOperation I guarantee you it has rot13(*abguvat* gb qb jvgu Terrx zlgubybtl).

Comment: that is a HUGE bounty for PSE

Comment: @im_so_meta_even_this_acronym It got attention, didn't it? :)

Comment: So now I have to wait seven days to get the answer!? :(

Comment: @Wolff Not if somebody solves it first :)

Comment: wow that's a big bounty!

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky Yes, it was a pretty tricky riddle. The theme is a misdirection, and the first line is a partial red herring. Therefore, it’s extremely easy to get thrown off track and end up on a wild goose chase. Fortunately I didn’t have to reveal the answer myself, as that would’ve been super depressing. +1 to all fellow puzzlers who gave this one a shot, and shoutout to Alconja for solving the riddle.

Comment: That was a tricky one. Too bad I couldn't solve it, but now at least I can sleep again :-) What really threw me off was "My start, *to there*, does transport sell". Sounds like "to there" refers to "Hell".

Comment: Ah, of course. After the lifespan of the riddle is over (18 upvotes, question hints provided, bounty placed, question answered), I finally get one random downvote. LOL, love you too @ random downvoter

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think the solution is:

> **CABOOSE**

---

Line by line:

*My beginning: steamy, but 2/5ths crazy*

> As [GrumpyLlama59](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/90472/5208) noted, this is cluing LOCOmotive (which is the front of the train, and the caboose is typically at the rear). It's somewhat of a red herring because it's talking about the physical beginning rather than the word's beginning.

*My middle, wailing, from spectres hazy*

> Ghosts say **BOO**

*My end, demonic, lives in Hell*

> **[OSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ose_(demon))** is a demon and the "Great President of Hell"

*My start, to there, does transport sell*

> A mode of transport you pay for is a taxi **CAB**

*My middle, within, the original man*

> Possibly, c**ABO**ose => **ABO**rigine (meaning original inhabitant)

*My end, ends, an ender of lifespan*

> A n**OOSE** ends lives (from OP in chat)

---

*Hint #1: All shall fear my reflection*

> Next few lines are based on the reverse of the word: ESOOBAC

*Its start starts matters of perplexion*

> **ESO**teric things are perplexing

*Its middle lives beyond the pale*

> Something "beyond the pale" is outside normal boundaries, or "**O**ut **O**f **B**and/bounds"

*Its end is my start's last tale*

> High **BAC** (Blood Alcohol Content) would be a CAB driver's last tale, either because of an accident or from losing their job (from OP in chat)

---

*Hint #2: ...*

> The line about "skulls, stopping, cackle and grin" is referring to the high mortality rate of the brakemen working in the caboose (from OP in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/52269290#52269290)). The rest is clarifying that the "beginning" (locomotive) is not the same as the "start" (cab...) and that Hint 1 isn't a real word.

---

*Hint #3: My beginning runs so desperately / From me why does it always flee?*

> Talking about the locomotive/caboose relationship. The locomotive is always "running away from" the rest of the train, which is being pulled along behind.

*My ends, each two, letters in sum / Are a mystery and madness to succumb*

> Two letters from each end, concatenated => **CA**boo**SE** => **CASE** => both "a mystery" (as in a police investigation) and "madness to succumb" (as in headcase or basket case)

---

*Hint #4: My letters are of number seven / Ask for more hints and I'll send you to heaven*

> Indeed CABOOSE has seven letters

---

*Title: I terrify those beneath*

> OP confirmed in chat that this was to set tone/theme of terror, literally referring to being run over by a train (though I'd argue that taking the slang usage of caboose => buttocks would terrify anyone trapped beneath too).

Answer (score 2):

My beginning: steamy, but 2/5ths crazy

> Locomotive. Locomotive can be powered by steam and 2/5ths of the word (= 4/10) is loco which is Spanish for crazy

My middle, wailing, from spectres hazy

> ghosts are often depicted saying **boo!**

My end, demonic, lives in Hell

> Could be several things, Devil, Satan, Demon, Imp, ect.

My start, to there, does transport sell

> The start is not the beginning, but the beginning is locomotive. So the start must be where you can sell trains or something carried by a train. Mayabe a **port**.

My middle, within, the original man

> The original man might be **Adam**. I'm not sure how many letters within Adam are needed.

My end, ends, an ender of lifespan

> The ender of lifespan might be **The Grim Reaper**. Again, not sure how many letters I'm looking for.

Comment: rot13(Avpr wbo! Lbh'er nyernql ba gur evtug genpx) You should probably add more details, though, or this is best left as a comment.

Comment: rot13(Ybbxf yvxr lbh tbg qr-envyrq. Erzrzore, nygubhtu lbhe qrqhpgvba sbe "zl ortvaavat" vf pbeerpg, "zl fgneg vf abg zl ortvaavat".)

Comment: Unfortunately, the first part is still the only correct part.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are:

> [Haunted Train: Spirits of Charon](https://www.bigfishgames.com/games/8719/haunted-train-spirits-of-charon-ce/)
>  (hidden object game from 2014 by Big Fish Games)

*My beginning: steamy, but 2/5ths crazy*

> By *beginning* you mean the beginning of the sentence. As @GrumpyLlama59 stated before me a *locomotive* is steam powered. It's a 10 letter word and the first 4 letters spell *loco*. So 4/10 = 2/5 of the word is *crazy*. Another word for locomotive is **train**.

*My middle, wailing, from spectres hazy*

> "Spectres" is another word for **spirits**.

*My end, demonic, lives in Hell*

> **Charon** is the ferryman of Hell from Greek mythology.

*My start, to there, does transport sell*

> By *start* you mean the start of the game where you get a ticket for the train of the dead from **Charon**, who transports the dead to the underworld.

*My middle, within, the original man*

> I don't understand this clue. (*The original man* might refer to *Adam* or maybe *Noah*.)

*My end, ends, an ender of lifespan*

> In the end of the game you kill Count Vladislav Orlok, a **vampire**, who are known to end people's lifes.

The hints:

> I don't understand the hints. (Except the part about the beginning being different from the start.)

Comment: Well, you're right that it's about rot13(genvaf), but wrong that it's about a rot13(tnzr). When you get it, the hints will match up.

Answer (score 0):

**Partial**

Maybe you are

> **locomen**? Found by applying a [Qat search](https://www.quinapalus.com/cgi-bin/qat?pat=loco...&ent=Search&dict=6) to find 7 letter words, as per Hint 4, that start with “loco,” as confirmed by the OP.

*My beginning: steamy, but 2/5ths crazy*

> As @GrumpyLlama59 found, this clues **LOCO**.

*My middle, wailing, from spectres hazy*

> Not sure about this one, maybe **COME** is something that spectres wail because they want your soul?

*My end, demonic, lives in Hell*

> This one is either **OMEN** as in “demonic omen,” or **MEN**, which there are a lot of in hell.

*My start, to there, does transport sell*

> No idea at all about this one, but given the below two clues, this may be a wordplay clue for **L**?

*My middle, within, the original man*

> This one is a wordplay clue: **OM** are the first letters of “original man”

*My end, ends, an ender of lifespan*

> Another wordplay one, this time with **N** being the last letter (“ender”) of the word “lifespan.”

However, I don’t know how this word fits all the hints. Some thoughts:

> - The “reflection” mentioned in Hints 1 and 2 is probably the word spelled backwards, which in this case is **NEMOCOL.** As Hint 2 states, that’s not a word, but I can’t get the parts of it to fit the clues from Hint 1 at all.
>  - “My ends, each two” from Hint 3 probably referees to the first and last letters, which are **LN.** But again, the hint doesn’t make any sense to me - I can’t think of anything mysterious or mad about those letters.
>  - I have no clue about any of the other hints, if there are any more.

Comment: rot13("Zl fgneg vf abg zl ortvaavat" Zl ortvaavat vf n ybpbzbgvir, ohg gur npghny jbeq qbrf abg pbagnva "YBPB" - zl fgneg vf fbzrguvat ryfr.) Your intuition about reflection is correct.

Comment: @Avi Ah, I should’ve read the hints more carefully, I’ll think about this some more then

Comment: No problem, good luck!